# Javadoc-like documentation for C/C++ libraries?

Tags: c, javadoc

Is there such a thing as Javadoc-type documentation available for C/C++ libraries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a javadoc-like program for C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809443/is-there-a-javadoc-like-program-for-c-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a javadoc-like program for C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809443/is-there-a-javadoc-like-program-for-c-c)

Comment: Also very near duplicate (asks for C++ only, not C): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141228/javadoc-like-documentation-for-c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javadoc-like Documentation for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141228/javadoc-like-documentation-for-c)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) for documenting your code.

If you mean documentation of existing libraries :

For the STL, check out the [sgi](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/) site.

For a general c/ c++ reference see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/).

For a specific library, check its site.

Comment: There are several possibilities (docbook, etc), but Doxygen has the advantage of understanding Javadoc format.  If you are accustomed to Javadoc, Doxygen is probably the most natural choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the chm book for your code by combining the doxygen with htmlhelp.exe. 
I use codeblocks, this has the easy wizard to produce the diagrams as well as the chmbook.