# Load references of a framework/library(openGL) inside an IDE

Tags: visual-studio, opengl

I am using Visual Studio 2012 for creating a graphics project using OpenGL 3.2 and higher. Whenever I write code, I always have two windows active: IDE and Firefox, with Firefox being open on Reference page of OpenGL.

I wonder if there is a way to take a reference file of OpenGL and load it into Visual Studio so it when I type a method/class/constant name it would give me a brief context on what this method/class/constant name is all about.

It is the case in Eclipse when I use libraries, it would show up with description, which is an incredibly useful feature to have.

Comment: A more general question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141228/javadoc-like-documentation-for-c